# When I print the creation time of a file, why is it +7:00 hours ahead of the actual file creation time?

Tags: c++, c, stat

A strange thing is happening when I print the creation time of a file in my program.
This problem happens on my Mac machine **as well as** my Windows machine.

The creation time my program outputs is **exactly 7 hours AHEAD** of the actual creation time(that i check in the file's properties).

For example, in properties, the creation time of a file is
06-02-2020 02:44:10 PM

The output of my program shows
06-02-2020 09:44:10 PM

And this +7:00 hour difference is true for all files I test (windows and mac).

This snippet of code in my program (working) is responsible for finding and printing creation time:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <iomanip>

//Converts Unix time to regular time
int convertEpochTime()
{
    std::uint32_t time_date_stamp = buf.st_ctime;
    std::time_t temp = time_date_stamp;
    std::tm* t = std::gmtime(&temp);
    std::cout << "[" << std::put_time(t, "%m-%d-%Y %I:%M:%S %p") << "]" << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}

//Gets file creation time
int main()
 {
    
     stat("testfile.txt",&buf);
     convertEpochTime();

     return 0;

 }
```

Why is there a +7:00 hour difference between the outputted creation time and the actual creation time? How can I fix this?

Comment: what's the difference between GMT and your local time

Comment: There is a way to fix this problem. Come to the UK. You will be put into quarantine. By the time that you finally emerge, it will be winter and local time will be GMT, and you will not notice any more discrepancy.

Comment: @alaniwi: the only downside with *that* solution is that you'll be in the UK. A subtle dig from an Aussie, no *real* offence intended :-)

Comment: @OP -- How is living in Colorado like these days :-) ?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie West coast I think, allowing for daylight saving.

Comment: Well, somewhere around those parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `gmtime` function gives you the UTC time (the `gm` refers to Greenwich mean time despite the fact they are subtly different things, one a *standard* and one a *zone*), not the local time. Hence you're almost certainly in a time zone seven hours away from UTC.

If you want local time, I'm *sure* there's a function lying around here somewhere. Oh, yes, there it is: `localtime` :-)

Comment: How did I not notice!! Thanks for being clear and concise. I really appreciate it